# Can I play second media source if I get error on first in exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am Beginner android. Can anyone help me in brief about this problem. I am getting two links dynamically

1. url
2. alternate

I want to play second media(alternate) source if I get an error on the first one (url).
I am searching this for a week, a good answer will be appreciated. if you unable to solve please upvote it to get into more eyes.. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my full code

```
ImageButton playPause,lockScreen,unLock;
SeekBar seekBar;
TextView start,end;
boolean isPlaying = false;
boolean isLock = false;
RelativeLayout controller;
FrameLayout root;

boolean isControllerShowing = true;
private Handler mHandler;


SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;

SessionManagement management;
String url, alternate;
Uri mp4VideoUri;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_tv);

    checkConnection();


    Sensey.getInstance().init(this);

    Sensey.getInstance().startOrientationDetection(15,this);

    management = new SessionManagement(this);

    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = management.getUserDetails();

    url = hashMap.get(SessionManagement.LIVE_URL);
    alternate = hashMap.get(SessionManagement.ALTERNATE_URL);


    playPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
    lockScreen = findViewById(R.id.btnLock);
    unLock = findViewById(R.id.btnOpenLock);

    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seeker);

    end = findViewById(R.id.duration);
    start = findViewById(R.id.position);

    controller = findViewById(R.id.layout_controller);
    root = findViewById(R.id.activity_live);

    try {
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
        simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(false);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();

        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);


            mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse(url); //Radnom 540p indian channel



        mHandler = new Handler();


        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new 
        DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "Madha TV"), bandwidthMeterA);

        DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
        final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);
        player.prepare(loopingSource);

        player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                switch (error.type) {
                    case ExoPlaybackException.TYPE_SOURCE:
                        Log.e("Error", "TYPE_SOURCE: " + error.getSourceException().getMessage());
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(LiveTVActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(LiveTVActivity.this, error.getSourceException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case ExoPlaybackException.TYPE_RENDERER:
                        break;

                    case ExoPlaybackException.TYPE_UNEXPECTED:
                        Log.e("Error", "TYPE_UNEXPECTED: " + error.getUnexpectedException().getMessage());
                        break;
                }

                player.stop();
                player.prepare(loopingSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true); //run file/link when ready to play.
        player.setVideoDebugListener(this); //for listening to resolution change and  outputing the resolution

        if (player.getPlayWhenReady())
        {
            playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.cvp_action_pause);
            isPlaying = true;
        }
        else
        {
            playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.cvp_action_play);
            isPlaying = false;
        }


        root.setOnClickListener(this);
        playPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        lockScreen.setOnClickListener(this);
        unLock.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Log.e("Error",e.toString());
    }

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
        }
        updateMetadata();

    } else {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        }
        updateMetadata();
    }

}


@Override
public void onTopSideUp() {
    updateMetadata();
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

@Override
public void onBottomSideUp() {

}

@Override
public void onRightSideUp() {
    updateMetadata();
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

@Override
public void onLeftSideUp() {
    updateMetadata();
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
}

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
private void updateMetadata() {
    Point displaySize;
    displaySize = Utils.getDisplaySize(this);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(displaySize.x,displaySize.y);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    simpleExoPlayerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    simpleExoPlayerView.invalidate();

}
private void checkConnection()
{
    boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
    showSnack(isConnected);
}

// Showing the status in Snackbar
private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {

    if (!isConnected) {
        Config.noConnection(LiveTVActivity.this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnPlayPause) {
        setPlayPause();
    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnLock) {
        if (!isLock)
        {
            unLock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isLock = true;
            controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            root.setClickable(false);
        }
    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnOpenLock)
    {
        if (isLock)
        {
            root.setClickable(true);
            isLock = false;
            unLock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            controller.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.activity_live)
    {
        showController();
    }
}

public void showController()
{
    if (!isControllerShowing)
    {
        isControllerShowing = true;
        controller.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        isControllerShowing = false;
        controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void setPlayPause() {

    if (isPlaying)
    {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        isPlaying = false;
        playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.cvp_action_play);
    }
    else
    {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isPlaying = true;
        playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.cvp_action_pause);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    showSnack(isConnected);
}

@Override
public void onVideoEnabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoDecoderInitialized(String decoderName, long initializedTimestampMs, long initializationDurationMs) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoInputFormatChanged(Format format) {

}

@Override
public void onDroppedFrames(int count, long elapsedMs) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
}

@Override
public void onRenderedFirstFrame(Surface surface) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoDisabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExoPlayer.EventListener {

private SimpleExoPlayer mSimpleExoPlayer;

private SimpleExoPlayerView mSimpleExoPlayerView;

private Handler mMainHandler;
private AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory mAdaptiveTrackSelectionFactory;
private TrackSelector mTrackSelector;
private LoadControl mLoadControl;
private DefaultBandwidthMeter mBandwidthMeter;
private DataSource.Factory mDataSourceFactory;
private SimpleCache mSimpleCache;
private DataSource.Factory mFactory;
private MediaSource mVideoSource;
private LoopingMediaSource mLoopingMediaSource;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private String videoUrl="http://sample.vodobox.net/skate_phantom_flex_4k/skate_phantom_flex_4k.m3u8";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    mSimpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.amPrgbrLoading);
}

/**
 * this method play audio and video with hls streaming.
 */
private void playMedia() {
    mMainHandler = new Handler();
    mBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    mAdaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(mBandwidthMeter);
    mTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(mAdaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);

    mLoadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    mSimpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, mTrackSelector, mLoadControl);

    mSimpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(mSimpleExoPlayer);
    mSimpleExoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlaybackControlView.VisibilityListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            mSimpleExoPlayerView.showController();
        }
    });
    mDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,Util.getUserAgent(this, "com.exoplayerdemo"), mBandwidthMeter);
    mSimpleCache = new SimpleCache(this.getCacheDir(), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(1024 * 1024 * 10));
    mFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(mSimpleCache, mDataSourceFactory,0);
    mVideoSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl),
            mFactory, mMainHandler, new AdaptiveMediaSourceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadStarted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs) {
            //Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Load Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCompleted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {
            //Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Load Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCanceled(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadError(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded, IOException error, boolean wasCanceled) {
            videoUrl=""; // define second url
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpstreamDiscarded(int trackType, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs) {
           // Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Up stream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownstreamFormatChanged(int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaTimeMs) {
           // Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Down Stream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mLoopingMediaSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mVideoSource);
    mSimpleExoPlayer.prepare(mLoopingMediaSource);
    mSimpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    mSimpleExoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    playMedia();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopMedia();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopMedia();
}

private void stopMedia() {
    mSimpleExoPlayer.stop();
    mSimpleExoPlayer.release();
}



@Override
public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

}

@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

}

@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

}
}
```

Comment: do we need to inialize second url or defining enough? @Android Team

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same issue. you have to do some change in your code 
1. implement exo player listen to the activity so the common lister will use every instant of your player

2. Then you have to add all the player initialize code in a method and call this on error state of exo player 
   **initializePlayer();**

   private void initializePlayer(String video_url) {

   try {
                   videoUri = Uri.parse(VIDEOS_URL + contentMasterModel.getImage_or_video());

   ```
   simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
                   TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                           new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);
                   trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

               player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

               simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
               //player.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);

               player.addListener(this);

               DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

               MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri,
                       mediaDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
               player.prepare(mediaSource);
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                   // Call some material design APIs here
                   // player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
               }

               inErrorState = false;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               Log.e("Please try again", "download again");
           }
       }
   ```

OnError

```
  private void errorinitializePlayer() {
  videoUri = Uri.parse(VIDEOS_URL);
                simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
                TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                        new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);

                trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

                player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

                simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
                //player.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);
                player.addListener(this);
                DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri,
                        mediaDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
                player.prepare(mediaSource);
                inErrorState = false;}
```

And implements EventListener, PlaybackControlView.VisibilityListener in activity

Comment: I am getting this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player)' on a null object reference @Ravi Jat

Comment: in my code  // expo player

    private SimpleExoPlayer player;

    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

Comment: iam getting same error again can you give your full code